# Adding prefix to a named route helper under namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

This is how a common namespace looks like.

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :posts
end
```

And it creates a named route like this one;

```
new_admin_post_path
```

Here's my question; how can I add a prefix (like "new" in this example) to a named route under namespace?

Let's say my route definition likes this one;

```
namespace :admin do
  get 'post/new' => 'posts#new', as: 'post'
end
```

And it's creates a named route like;

```
admin_post_path
```

I want to add "new" prefix to this named route and make it look like `new_admin_post_path` and I don't want to use `resources`.

Comment: does your posts controller reside in the admin namespace? If yes then you can achieve it from the first way that you have written.

Comment: Yes it does. But I don't want to do this using or customizing with `resources` method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just try the code in routes.

```
namespace :admin, as: '' do
   get '/post/new' => 'posts#new', as: 'new_admin_post'
end
```

If you don't want to make admin namespace as nil, then you can do it. for that you need to put that route out of the namespace :admin block in routes

```
namespace :admin do
   # your other routes
end

get '/admin/post/new' => 'admin/posts#new', :as => 'new_admin_post'
```

Comment: There are other routes mapped under `admin` namespace so there is no point to drop "admin" prefixes and omit every single one manually. If it's possible I want to able to add prefixes to a named routes under namespaces, like `resources` able to do.

Comment: I don't like the idea of forced to getting the route out of the namespace but I think I'll go with this solution for now. I checked quite a bit of options out and read some source code but it is pretty much time consuming for a problem like this one.

Comment: Yes, the idea is not as per the rails structure. if you will find some better solution for this in between, please post it here.